# Removing words in a list that appear infrequently

Tags: list, python-2.7, text, token

I'm have a number of documents that I have tokenized and turned into lists with the tokens as the elements - I then inserted all of these lists into a list so that I have a list of lists of tokens.

Simple Example:

```
[["egg","apple","bread","milk","pear"], ["egg","apple","bread","milk"], ["egg","apple","bread","milk"]]
```

I want to remove tokens that appear in less than x% of the documents (for instance "pear" in the above since it only appears in one document out of three.) However, I'm not sure how to do this in an efficient manner - I know that the data structure might be problematic, but I need the output to be in this format for the next part of my code.

My current code looks like this and is obviously not very efficient when there are many documents:

```
min_docs = 0.05*len(tokenized_document_list)
whitelist = []
for document in tokenized_document_list: #Go through each document
    for token in document: #Go through each token in each document
        if token in whitelist:
            continue
        else:
            token_count = 0
            for document_t in tokenized_document_list: #Go through each document looking for token
                if token in document_t:
                    token_count = token_count + 1
                    if token_count > min_docs:
                        whitelist.append(token)
                        break
            if token_count < min_docs:
                document.remove(token)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import six


def calc_token_frequencies(doc_list):
    frequencies = defaultdict(int)  # Each dict item will start off as int(0)
    for token_set in doc_list:
        for token in token_set:
            frequencies[token] += 1
    return frequencies


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Use a list of sets here in order to leverage set features
    tokenized_document_list = [{"egg", "apple", "bread", "milk", "pear"},
                               {"egg", "apple", "bread", "milk"},
                               {"egg", "apple", "bread", "milk"}]

    # Count the number of documents each token was in.
    token_frequencies = calc_token_frequencies(tokenized_document_list)

    # I used 50% here instead of the example 5% so that it would do something useful.
    token_min_docs = 0.5*len(tokenized_document_list)

    # Calculate the black list via set comprehension.
    token_blacklist = {token for token, doc_count in six.iteritems(token_frequencies)
                       if doc_count < token_min_docs}

    # Remove items on the black list
    for doc_tokens in tokenized_document_list:
        doc_tokens.difference_update(token_blacklist)

    print tokenized_document_list
```

Comment: I should have clarified that I need to keep the number of times a term appears in a document, which makes using a set problematic. However, the change was quite simple from this solution - thank you!